# No underlying data for Excel Pivot Table value

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

On every other row value in a pivot table I'm able to double click the value to see the underlying data that is summed to produce the value, except for 1 row where double clicking the values shows a table with no data at all... Is anyone able to shed any light on where Excel produced this value from? Do pivot tables hold values after the underlying data has been deleted? The table has been refreshed.

There is no security on the sheet and this row is not a Total.

Comment: Right Click PT, & check `Refresh the Pivot Table when opening the file` option from the appeared dialogue. ☺

Comment: What data does your pivot table have and what data does that row have?

Comment: Could you provide a sample or screenshot about your problem?